# Mat-datepicker value autoselected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am creating a reminder app and am unable to set the date (more like prefill) in mat-datepicker.
I have an object

```
  resObj = {
    "taskId": 230,
    "whenToDo": "2020-05-10T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "wherToGo": "CityHall",
    "whatTodo": "Talk to mentor"
  }
```

In the .ts file I am changing the format of date on ngOnit() to 10/04/2020

```
    this.doj = this.resObj.dojs

    this.doj = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.resObj.dojs, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

and in the HTML

```
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <input  [(ngModel)]="doj" name="dojs"  matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date of Joining">
                                <mat-icon matSuffix>
                                    <img src="../../../assets/images/icons/purple_icons/icon-calendar.png" (click)="picker.open()">
                                </mat-icon>
                                <mat-datepicker #picker touchUi></mat-datepicker>
                            </mat-form-field>
```

Is there a way we can set the date above, selected in the datepicker when the user opens the page, and also the the dates starting from "today's date and before" should be disabled.

Comment: You want to set a default date somewhere in the code (meaning hard coded) and disable any dates before and including today's date, correct? If yes, what should the default date be?

Comment: @igg  yes disbale dates including today and before today, also, the default date will be the one in the object, i.e in the resObj -> whenToDo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default date by adding `[formControl]`.
You can set the `[min]` value for disabling the days before today.

```
 <mat-form-field>
  <input [(ngModel)]="doj" name="dojs" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date of Joining"
    [formControl]="defaultDate" [min]="minDate">
  <mat-icon matSuffix>
    <img src="../../../assets/images/icons/purple_icons/icon-calendar.png" (click)="picker.open()">
  </mat-icon>
  <mat-datepicker #picker touchUi></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

and set the values inside the .ts file.

```
defaultDate = new FormControl(new Date(resObj.whenToDo))
```

To disable today and past days,

```
minDate: Date;

ngOnInit() { 
  this.minDate = new Date();
  this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate() + 1)
}
```